# YARN Containers and Spark Executors

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I currently have a functioning cluster of 1 Driver(8 cores and 32GB RAM) and 2 Workers (One of 8cores and 32gb RAM other of 8cores and 16gb RAM)

However I seem to have a little confusion between the Containers generated and Spark Executors in order to maximize efficiency.

My current Configs are the following:

Worker 1:
[image]

Worker 2:
[image]

and my SparkSession Configs are these:

[image]

I would expect to get 3 Containers running in Yarn, 1 for driver and 2 for Spark, however the output I'm getting is the following:

[image]
[image]

Only two Containers, which one is allocated for RM and the second one for Worker. However only one if my workers (the one with 16gb RAM) is creating an executor, why is the other one not creating an executor?

How can I achieve maximum resource usage to have a high speed Spark Application